# invalid property id error while passing data in json format

Tags: php, javascript, json, flot

I have a some data in JSON format(which comes from php) to be passed to a javascript function. I'm getting 'invalid property id' error when I try to  do this.

```
Error: invalid property id
Source File: http://localhost/MathVoyager/index.php/test
Line: 1, Column: 15
Source Code:
draw_quadratic({
```

Below is the js function signature(both data and options are in JSON format)

function draw_quadratic(data, options, alpha, beta)

Below is a sample function call.

```
draw_quadratic({"label":"(((1)*x^((1))+(4))*((1)*x^((1))+(6))) = (0)","data":[[-8,8],[-7.5,5.25],[-7,3],[-6.5,1.25],[-6,0],[-5.5,-0.75],[-5,-1],[-4.5,-0.75],[-4,0],[-3.5,1.25],[-3,3],[-2.5,5.25],[-2,8]],"xaxis":1,"yaxis":1}, {"series":{"points":{"show":true},"lines":{"show":true}},"grid":{"hoverable":true,"clickable":true}}, 4, 8);
```

(I'm trying to plot some graph using flot js library)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok, My stupid mistake. The problem was with html code . I wrote

<body onload="draw_quadratic({$data}, {$options}, {$alpha}, {$beta});">

(i'm using smarty templating)

So the double quote in the json string ended the onload prematurely .

Replacing the double quotes with single quotes fixed the problem.

Thank for all replies.

Comment: Use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your json.

Answer (score -1):

```
mydata= JSON.parse('{"label":"(((1)*x^((1))+(4))*((1)*x^((1))+(6))) = (0)","data":[[-8,8],[-7.5,5.25],[-7,3],[-6.5,1.25],[-6,0],[-5.5,-0.75],[-5,-1],[-4.5,-0.75],[-4,0],[-3.5,1.25],[-3,3],[-2.5,5.25],[-2,8]],"xaxis":1,"yaxis":1}');
myoptions= JSON.parse('{"series":{"points":{"show":true},"lines":{"show":true}},"grid":{"hoverable":true,"clickable":true}}');  
draw_quadratic( mydata,myoptions,4,8);
```

Don't forget `''` or `""` when sending parameters to jsonparse it takes a string

- [www.JSON.org/json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)
- [www.JSON.org/js.html](http://www.JSON.org/js.html)

In php you can use:

- .json_decode — Decodes a JSON string
- .json_encode — Returns the JSON representation of a value

The code I wrote works with me in Chrome.